# Redirect on kernel request

Tags: php, symfony

The website to my project can be accessed via subdomains, e.g. `https://1234.example.com` The subdomains consist of four numeric values and represent an id for a special user entity. So when a request is made, I have to check if that id really exists, and if not, I want to redirect to the root url `https://www.example.com`. If the user used a correct id, nothing needs to be done.
I made an event listener and checked the existance of the id. That works like expected. But the redirect to the root url won't work:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    $hostArray = explode('.', $request->getHost());
    $subdomain = $hostArray[0];

    array_shift($hostArray);
    $host = implode('.', $hostArray);

    if (!is_numeric($hostArray[0])) {
        return new RedirectResponse($host);
    }

    $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(['id' => $subdomain]);
    if (null === $user) {
        return new RedirectResponse($host);
    }
}
```

The url doesn't change even if the id does not exists. When I step debug the code I can see that he reaches the RedirectResponse. But nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listeners are not suppose to return anything. If you want to trigger a redirect, set a response on the event:

```php
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $hostArray = explode('.', $event->getRequest()->getHost());
    $subdomain = $hostArray[0];

    array_shift($hostArray);
    $host = implode('.', $hostArray);

    if (is_numeric($subdomain) && $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(['id' => $subdomain])) {
        // you can pass the user as an attribute if you need him later
        $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('user', $user);

        return;
    }

    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($host));
}
```

Comment: I had to make some simple changes to your code (there is no method isMasterRequest() in 2.3.11, missing 'new' before RedirectResponse and the semicolon at the wrong position) ;) But then it works great. Thank you!!